# Delete row after application.match

Tags: excel, vba, match, delete-row

I can't figure out why it is not deleting the row if the user selects no.
I even tried telling to delete a certain line in the ws but it still did not delete that row
Adding the data if it is not there works.
If it is already there the message box does pop up.
The  only function that is not working is the delete.

```
Sub Submit_Data()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
Dim App As New Excel.Application
Dim wBook As Excel.Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet, id, v, m
Dim FileName As String
 
Dim CurrentJob As Long
Dim CurrentRow As Variant '<--- NOTE
Dim CurrentCell As Variant

 
Dim iRow As Long
 
FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\database.xlsm"
 
'Check File Exist or Not
 
'If Dir(FileName) = "" Then
 
    'MsgBox "Database File is missing. Unable to proceed.", vbOKOnly vbCritical, "Error"
    
    'Exit Sub
 
'End If
 
Set wBook = App.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
 
App.Visible = False
 
If wBook.ReadOnly = True Then
    TryWriteMode book:=wBook _
               , numberOfTries:=4 _
               , secondsWaitAfterFailedTry:=10
          ' MsgBox "test", vbInformation
            
End If
If wBook.ReadOnly Then
    MsgBox "Database is in use. Please try again later.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Read-only book"
    Exit Sub
End If
 
 'Transfer the Data
     id = TextBox2.Value
     With wBook.Sheets("database")
        Set ws = wBook.Sheets("database")
       ' m = Application.Match(id, ws.[B:B], 0)      'try to match an existing row

       
       m = Application.Match(id, 5, 0)
        



CurrentJob = TextBox2.Value
CurrentRow = Application.Match(CurrentJob, ws.Range("B:B"), 0)
CurrentCell = ws.Cells(CurrentRow, 1)

    If IsError(CurrentRow) Then
             
             iRow = .Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
             .Range("A" & iRow).Value = TextBox1.Value 'Cell
             .Range("B" & iRow).Value = TextBox2.Value   'workorder number
             .Range("C" & iRow).Value = TextBox3.Value   'product number
             .Range("D" & iRow).Value = TextBox4.Value    'Work order quanity
    
    
    
Else

MsgBox "JOB ALREADY ASSIGNED TO " & CurrentCell & vbNewLine & "DO YOU WANT TO KEEP IT THIER ", vbYesNo

If Result = vbNo Then

ws.Rows(CurrentRow).EntireRow.Delete


End If


End If
   
        
       End With
         
       wBook.Close Savechanges:=True
       App.Quit
         
       Set App = Nothing
         
       'Reset the form
       Call resetForm
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       
End Sub
```

Comment: this is a lot of code but I'm asuming you mean `If Result = vbNo Then ws.Rows(CurrentRow).EntireRow.Delete End If` is so the code appears to work as long as `ws` and `CurrentRow` are well defined.  if you put a `stop` just before it and look at the locals window (View-> locals window) are ws and CurrentRow both defined how you would expect?

Comment: Yes that is the area am talking about I put the stops in and all the values are correct I even tired ws.Rows(10).EntireRow.Delete and it still did not work.

Comment: try removing the ws and just see if it works on the active workbook, though be careful what work book you target.  like i say that line is working for me

Comment: You didn't save the returned value from the msgbox. `Result` is not defined. I think you forgot to add the part `Result = ` on the previous line.

Comment: Thank you I forgot to define result